# Where should user application user project files be saved on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I have been scratching my head to find what is the standard:

I have a software program I have created and ported to Mac.

Should project files created and explicitly saved by a user - and each containing a subfolder with data and tons of project settings - default to be stored in:

```
~Documents/company/program/
```

or

```
~/Library/Application Support/company/program/
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your program lets the user manage projects. There are a couple of standardish approaches, and which location you should use depends on which approach your program takes:

- The projects can be treated essentially treated as documents -- that is, when when the user saves or opens a project, they get a "browser" that lets them choose the location it'll be saved to/opened from. Also, they can see projects in the Finder, copy them (including backing up, copying to other accounts or computers, etc), move them, etc. In this case you should default to ~/Documents, or possibly a subfolder of it. You should probably also make your projects ["document packages"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html), meaning that the Finder will show them as single items (rather than folders), making it less likely users will make mistakes like copying only part of a project, "reorganizing" the contents of a project folder, etc. This also means double-clicking a project "package" can open your app directly.
- The projects can be managed by your program, i.e. the user just sees something like a list of project names to work with, and when saving they do something like just give it a name and your program controls where it's stored. In this case, your program is responsible for providing capabilities to move, copy, back up, etc projects. In this case, you should store the projects in ~/Library/Application Support/YourProgramName.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is "standard", but there are common practices: data should go to `~/Documents`, settings to `~/Library/Application Support`.

---

By default, `~/Library` folder on OS X is hidden in Finder.

If you save data files which user has to reference later, you are effectively creating trouble for users and support requests for yourself.

On the other hand settings, which user can alter with the GUI of your application, should be placed in `~/Library`.

Comment: Would it be standard to have my software create a sub-folder with he company/program name in the documents folder? I feel that it would be a convenience. You could compare the data to that of saving a larger document structure in an office tool

Comment: Yea, but you are slowly getting into detailed programming questions. Please search Apple documentation and StackOverflow. For a start answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185813/writing-to-library-application-support-folder-in-mac-os-x-10-7).